# cakephp 2 - pagination - don't pass variable in url

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a search form which, if someone fills it in and there are no results to report, I want to make them aware of that but then show them a result set of my choosing. The problem is that when I show them this result set of my choosing and I use the paginator helpers for prev/next they want to pass the search term which is in my URL along with the page number.

That obviously causes problems because there isn't a page:2 for the results search:termHasNoResults

How can I stop the paginator helper passing my search variable in the URL when I'm showing them my alternative result set?

Thanks

Comment: Basically is there a way to restrict what params get automatically appended to the URL when you use any type of link?

Comment: why don't you append a condition to your pagination config? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Comment: you can also add something like '?' => 'keyword='.$this->request->query['keyword'] to the options as well to store the keyword in the url string

Answer (score 0):

Use
`$this->Paginator->options('url' => array(

    'controller' => 'YOUR CONTROLLER', 'action' => 'YOUR ACTION', 'OTHER PARAMS');`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 'url' option to pagination in your view like this:

```
$url = array_merge($this->request->pass, $this->request->named);
unset($url['page']);
$parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
if (count($parts) == 2) {
    $url['?'] = $parts[1];
}
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'url' => $url,
));
```

More here: http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-PaginatorHelper.html
and here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper::options

If you widely use filters and additional url params - make an element which will handle it for you